# SVG <image> tag not exported to canvas

Tags: javascript, image, svg, canvas, export

I have an issue exporting an SVG with `image` tag through a canvas element to PNG. Apologies if this has been asked before but I could not find a relevant question myself.

The svg and code example below should explain it better, below is my SVG (I've also tried with a URL instead of a local file in `image` tag's `xlink:href` attribute, with the same result):

```html
<svg
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  style="
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    min-width: 250px;
    min-height: 190px;
  "
  viewBox="-100 -100 300 300"
>
  <g>
    <g />
    <g>
      <g style="visibility: visible">
        <image
          x="199"
          y="139"
          width="50"
          height="50"
          xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          xlink:href="http://localhost:5173/test.png"
          preserveAspectRatio="none"
          opacity="1"
        />
      </g>
      <g style="">
        <g>
          <foreignObject
            style="overflow: visible; text-align: left"
            pointer-events="none"
            width="100%"
            height="100%"
          >
            <div
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
              style="
                display: flex;
                align-items: unsafe center;
                justify-content: unsafe center;
                width: 48px;
                height: 1px;
                padding-top: 164px;
                margin-left: 200px;
              "
            >
              <div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center">
                <div
                  style="
                    display: inline-block;
                    font-size: 14px;
                    font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
                    color: #252b3a;
                    line-height: 1.2;
                    pointer-events: all;
                    white-space: normal;
                    word-wrap: break-all;
                  "
                >
                  Image Test
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </foreignObject>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g />
    <g />
  </g>
</svg>
```

---

Below is the code I use to load the svgString to an image, and convert it into dataURL through `HTMLCanvasElement`'s `toDataURL` method:

```js
const img = new Image();
img.onload = () => {
  // Draw the Image object onto the canvas
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;

  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

  const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(`image/png`);
  // This dataURL does not render my image, even though it is there in the SVG
};

// Setting img's width and height according to prior calculations
img.width = width;
img.height = height;
img.src = `data:image/svg+xml;base64,${window.btoa(svgString)}`;
```

Comment: you'd have to convert xlink:href="http://localhost:5173/test.png" to a data url, then convert the whole SVG to a data url. I.e. you need a data url within a data url.

Comment: I've solved the issue with the approach you mentioned. I've posted my answer in a seperate comment as well, you can check it out if you want.

Thanks a lot, @RobertLongson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used Robert Longson's answer, which is to load the image data and convert it to Base64. Here's how I accomplished it:

```js
function imageToDataURL(imageUrl: string): Promise<string | ArrayBuffer> {
  return fetch(imageUrl)
    .then((response) => response.blob())
    .then((blob) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function () {
          resolve(reader.result);
        };
        reader.onerror = reject;
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
      });
    });
}
```

The function above returns a promise, which will be resolved as a DataURL once the image is successfully loaded. Then I called it to convert my `image` tags within my SVG element, like so:

```js
// I'm calling this in an async function, hence await is available
const images = svg.querySelectorAll("image");
for (const i in images) {
  if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(images, i)) {
    const img = images[i];
    const imgHref = img.getAttribute("xlink:href");
    const dataURL = (await this.imageToDataURL(imgHref)) as string;
    img.setAttribute("xlink:href", dataURL);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What is this dollar with curly brackets? Some 3rd party library you didn't bother to mention?

```
img.src = `data:image/svg+xml;base64,${window.btoa(svgString)}`;
```

I would replace that non-standard JS with this...

```
img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(svgString))); // <-- it has to be encoded!
```

But anyway, why do even need that line? Are you saving to disk? That's what dataURLs are used for!

Any rendering should take place with...

```
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
```

That's all you need, so you can remove the dataURL line.

But anyway, the problem is your viewbox... you can temporarily disable viewbox by adding an "x" to it and you'll see your image...

```
XviewBox="-100 -100 300 300"
```

I can see *my* image with your script when I disable viewBox!

Good luck.

Comment: Dollar with curly brackets is template literals and I believe it is a standard JS functionality: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

My issue was not with the viewbox particularly, I had issue resolving an image on a canvas (with a relative path or a URL). Robert Longson had posted an approach which has worked out for me, and I've posted my implementation of that idea in a seperate comment.